# How to optimize two ranges for the determination of the intersection point between two curves

Tags: excel, vba

I start this thread asking for your help in Excel.
The main goal is to determine the coordinates of the intersection point P=(x,y) between two curves (curve A, curve B) modeled by points.
The curves are non-linear and each defining point is determined using complex equations (equations are dependent by a lot of parameters chosen by user, as well as user will choose the number of points which will define the accuracy of the curves). That is to say that each curve (curve A and curve B) is always changing in the plane XY (Z coordinate is always zero, we are working on the XY plane) according to the input parameters and the number of the defining points is also depending by the user choice.

My first attempt was to determine the intersection point through the trend equations of each curve (I used the LINEST function to determine the coefficients of the polynomial equation) and by solving the solution putting them into a system. The problem is that Excel is not interpolating very well the curves because they are too wide, then the intersection point (the solution of the system) is very far from the real solution.
Then, what I want to do is to shorten the ranges of points to be able to find two defining trend equations for the curves, cutting away the portion of curves where cannot exist the intersection.

Today, in order to find the solution, I plot the curves on Siemens NX cad using multi-segment splines with order 3 and then I can easily find the coordinates of the intersection point. Please notice that I am using the multi-segment splines to be more precise with the approximation of the functions curve A and curve B.

Since I want to avoid the CAD tool and stay always on Excel, is there a way to select a shorter range of the defining points close to the intersection point in order to better approximate curve A and curve B with trend equations (Linest function with 4 points and 3rd order spline) and then find the solution?

I attach a picture to give you an example of Curve A and Curve B on the plane:
https://postimg.cc/MfnKYqtk

At the following link you can find the Excel file with the coordinate points and the curve plot:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/jqph8jrnin0i7g1/intersection.xlsx/file

I hope to solve this problem with your help, thank you in advance!
kalo86

Comment: This is off topic here - there is a **Overflow** site specifically fore mathematics. Voting to close as this is not a coding problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question gave me some days of thinking and research.
With the help of https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

> § 27 - Intersections (Line-line intersections)

and

> § 28 - Curve/curve intersection

your problem can be solved in Excel.

About the mystery of Excel smoothed lines you find details here:
https://blog.splitwise.com/2012/01/31/mystery-solved-the-secret-of-excel-curved-line-interpolation/

The author of this fit is Dr. Brian T. Murphy, PhD, PE from www.xlrotor.com. You find details here:
https://www.xlrotor.com/index.php/our-company/about-dr-murphy
https://www.xlrotor.com/index.php/knowledge-center/files
=>see  Smooth_curve_bezier_example_file.xls
https://www.xlrotor.com/smooth_curve_bezier_example_file.zip

These knitted together you get the **following results** for the intersection of your given curves:

```
for the straight line intersection:
(x = -1,02914127711195 / y = 23,2340949174492)

for the smooth line intersection:
(x = -1,02947493047196 / y = 23,2370611219553)
```

For a full automation of your task you would need to add more details regarding the needed accuracy and what details you need for further processing (and this is actually not the scope of this website ;-).


**Intersection of the straight lines:**

[image]


**Intersection of the smoothed lines:**

[image]


**comparison charts:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solution,

Thank you very much for the anwer, you perfectly centered my goal.
Your solution (for the smoothed lines) is very very close to what I determine in Siemens NX.
I'm going to read the documentation at the provided link https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ in order to better understand the math behind this argument.

Then, to resume my request, you have been able to find the coordinates (x,y) of the intersection point between two curves without passing through an advanced CAD system with a very good precision.

I am starting to study now, best regards!

kalo86